# My User_ID miration says interger not integer. How do I change it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My User_ID miration says interger not integer.

```rb
class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pins, :user_id, :interger
    add_index :pins, :user_id
  end
end
```

I'm assuming I just can't change it from "interger" to "integer" using my text editor because it should be in my tables too.

Comment: Is this the last migration? or in between ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about in between. But here is an image of my migrations http://postimg.org/delete/ij6ooq1lm/

Comment: It should be 100% safe to change it directly in the migration. This kind of typo will raise an exception which means that it has not be run yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way :

(A) First grab the specific migration number:

```
[shreyas@Arup-iMac rails_app_test (master)]$ rake db:migrate:status

database: app_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150219075735  Create people
   up     20150219085131  Add likes to persons
   up     20150219114058  Add email to people

[shreyas@Arup-iMac rails_app_test (master)]$
```

(B) Now suppose, you want to edit the *migration* , **20150219085131**, then do :

```
bin/rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20150219085131
```

(C) Then edit your migration and fix what you want to fix :

```
class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pins, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :pins, :user_id
  end
end
```

(D) And finally, again :

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20150219085131
```

And you are done!

And If you are not able to run the current migration, then no worry, just change the file content by *hand*, and run **rake db:migrate**.

Comment: I think the migration couldn't have been run at all, because integer is not a defined type.

Comment: I meant "interger" instead of integer in my comment of course. integer is defined.

Comment: Yeah even though i had interger it still ran. I found that weird too.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your migration like this:

```
class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_reference :pins, :user, index: true
  end

  def down
    remove_index :pins, :user_id
    remove_column :pins, :user_id
  end
end
```

You rollback that migration:

bin/rake db:migrate:down VERSION=*version_number*

And try again:

bin/rake db:migrate:up VERSION=*version_number*

Comment: OP knew it.. How to change,, the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to `:integer` and then you have to run the migration, which will put the column in your db-tables:

```
rake db:migrate
```

If you try to run the migration like this it should show an error like:

```
type "interger" does not exist
```